# Regular security checks on server

Tags: server, security

I am administrating a server and obviously i am slightly paranoid if its security is compromised. Hence i regularly try to check if the security is still intact. Here are the things that i do roughly twice a week, maybe you could comment on it and/or give some additions.

I do:

1. Run `chkrootkit` and `rkhunter`
2. check `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep opened | grep sshd:session` For user logins (i know who is on vacation, hence these people should not login)
3. Check `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep opened | grep root` to see if somebody gained root access (despite me)
4. Loosely check the running tasks if something suspicious pops up

I do not really want to discuss safety measures, but rather how you check the security-integrity on a regular basis in few time (the stuff i do takes roughly 10 minutes).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am aware that there are many answered questions about how to secure a server, i rather want to know how you check on a day to day basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is more for if you just want to simplify / automate different tasks you do using scripts and crontab.

You can set up a script that you can run whenever you wish.

```
#!/bin/bash

chkrootkit
rkhunter

cat /var/log/auth.log | grep opened | grep sshd:session | more
#the ' | more' splits output into multiple screens, you can cut it off if you want

read
#delays the next command, waits until you press enter to move on, again, uncomment if you are doing this automatically

cat /var/log/auth.log | grep opened | grep root | more
read
#same as previous command

ps aux          
#change this to whatever command you use to check processes...

read
```

Just modify the script however you see fit. Make sure it is executable with `chmod +x myNewScript.sh`. Run this (`bash /path/to/script/myNewScript.sh`) whenever you want.

You can also alias this command by putting `alias secCheck='bash /path/to/script/myNewScript.sh` in your `.bashrc` file (home dir). Then just run `secCheck` at any time whenever you want to check security.

If you want to make the script automated, as in no user interaction needed, remove all `read`'s and output the cat's somewhere to maybe check later, etc. You can then set up [crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to run the script as frequently as you like.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally suggest a piece of software called [OSSEC HIDS](https://ossec.github.io/downloads.html) (Host Intrusion Detection System) which if configured properly (which is reasonably easy to do so, just follow the installer) will regularly send you system and security related information such as what is listening on which port, if the hashsums of any important files have been changed, when software is installed, removed, purged, or upgraded, if any adapters enter promiscuous mode, etc. It is also highly customizable so you can change what it alerts you about and increase certain alerts such as the files it monitors.

I would also suggest that you regularly scan your server with an AV such as `clamav` which can be installed with.

And that you setup `fail2ban` to block any hackers trying to login into your server many times trying to brute force their way in.

Comment: I have fail2ban up, there are really a lot of people from China trying to brute force the  server :-) OSSEC sounds interesting, thanks for the suggestion.